# CodeIgniter and mod_rewrite with multiple applications

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use CodeIgniter for multiple applications along with mod_rewrite for the application folder/name.

My CodeIgniter structure is as follows:

```
webroot/appone/
webroot/apptwo/
webroot/system/
webroot/index.php
webroot/appone.php
webroot/apptwo.php
```

I followed the example listed here to use CI with multiple apps. http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Multiple_Applications/

I'm looking to use mod_rewrite that will show the following:

```
domain.com/appone/
domain.com/apptwo/
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but shouldn't you have two .htacess files, both in the corresponding appone/apptwo folders?

Comment: So do I need to remove the root appone.php file and use an index.php in the appone folder that loads all of the systems files etc?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it would make sense since you have two application folders for different sites. They share the same core, but in theory you could have to completely different htaccess files. Do keep the appone.php and apptwo.php files though, I'm not 100% sure. EDIT @fdias shared an excellent .htacess file you could use in both application folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Dirk is correct.

Here's the code I'm using (got it from Elliot Haughin) on every app folder and it works fine. Just change APP_FOLDER_NAME to whatever you wish appone, apptwo etc.

have an .htaccess file on each folder with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /APP_FOLDER_NAME

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

PS. Don't forget to remove the index.php and define base url on CI config.

Cheers.