# routing requests with htaccess and codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter app with one controller (main.php)

Currently, I have the htaccess file set to remove the index.php and the main.php

So instead of www.domain.com/index.php/main/function_name, it's just www.domain.com/function_name

My htaccess files looks like this:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/main/$1 [L]
```

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

I now need to add a large piece to the site. It's currently built in a seperate codeigniter app, and I need to move it over. The new part of the site is in controllers/manage_emails/contacts.php...

My question is, how do I change the htaccess file to remove the main.php from the URL for most of the time, but then if you put in www.domain.com/manage_emails/contollername it would go to the proper controller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand there are 2 separate problems you have:

1.remove the index.php file from Codeigniter's default

2.redirect any call from 'www.domain.com/main/method' to 'www.domain.com/method'

For the first problem, I always use Elliot Haughin's htaccess file for CI: [CodeIgniter and mod_rewrite with multiple applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057519/codeigniter-and-mod-rewrite-with-multiple-applications)

For your second problem, you need to change config/routes.php in CI, and add this line:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "main/$1";
```

..and you can also check this post:[Codeigniter, bypassing the main or default controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233670/codeigniter-bypassing-the-main-or-default-controller/16234599?noredirect=1#comment23227401_16234599)

Try to separate these 2 problems, and like it has been said, stick with CI for routing and just use htaccess for removing index.php from URL.

Comment: Its really 3 problems... because I also need to access controllers in the controllers/manage_emails/something.php folder as well

Comment: Did you check the second link? This covers your third problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your application would be a lot easier to manage if you remove any URI routing from the .htaccess file, and let your CodeIgniter's routes do that for you.

Your .htaccess should have just the standard "get rid of index.php" code (the last part, without the `/main` in it). Then your application's routes can define when/where the rest of the URLs will go.

Slightly unrelated FYI, if you are using a more recent version of CI such as 2.1.x, you don't need the system and application folder-specific rules in your .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks, so what would my routes be to redirect everything to main.php except for /manage_emails/controllername

Comment: Read the documentation, the routes functionality hasn't changed. It's fairly simple, you should only need two routes.

Answer (score 1):

In addtion to @despina answer i want to add something:

You have to set `$route['(:any)'] = "main/$1";` at the last route because CI  handle the routes in the order in which they appear on your routes.php file, so if you put $route['(:any)'] at the top, it will handle anything.

so your route.php file will be something like that:

```
$route['controllers/manage_emails/something.php'] = 'controllers/manage_emails/something.php'
$route['(:any)'] = "main/$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your 2 rules are not correct and most likely not working. Here is the fixed version of your .htaccess with addition of one new rule that have asked for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(?:application|system)(/.*|)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/manage_emails/contollername [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/main/$1 [L]
```

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

Comment: THanks, this doesn't seem to be working though... Not sure if my question was clear, but manage_emails is a sub folder within the controllers folder... Then within that manage_emails folder I have a bunch of various controllers that I want to access.

Comment: @Bill: When you access any of the controllers inside `manage_emails folder` what are those URLs exactly? I'm also confused with `?` in this line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/main/$1 [L]` of your question. Are you sure `?` is required after `index.php`.

Comment: So the URL would be: domain.com/welcome would map to controllers->main.php/welcome All the functionality for the site is within main.php. I need to add a separate section which is in controllers->manage_emails->controllername.php/somefunction I want everything to work the way it is now, except also be able to access the controllers within the manage_emails folder. I'm not sure what the ? does in the htaccess file I have, but the htaccess file works to remove index.php and main.php from the URL. So I just need to add the other thing now.

Answer (score 0):

```
//config/routes.php
    $route['404_override'] = 'main/route';
//controllers/main.php
class Main {
...........
   function route() {
      $methodName = $this->uri->segment(1);
      if(method_exists($methodName, $this)) {
       $this->{$methodName}();
      } else {
        show_404();
      }
   }
}
```