# Codeigniter, bypassing the main or default controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

i tried to find solution, but i think i am quite doing something wrong here,

i hope any one with good knowledge of codeigniter routing can help me in this regard.

what i want is that,

i have default controller named `main`

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

my site urls are like

```
mydomain.com/main/#home
mydomain.com/main/#search
mydomain.com/main/#login
```

what i want is to remove/hide the `main` from center and links can directly work.
like this

`mydomain.com/#home`

however i did succeeded a little using codeigniter documentation.
This is what i did to achieve it.
in route file i added this

```
$route['(:any)'] = "main/$1";
```

it worked but it messed up with other links.

First now `domain.com/main/#home` stopped working.
second, now i cant have other controller name here??

i mean if i try this `domain.com/virtualvault/#search`, it wont work..

What i am trying to have that,
When i go to `domain.com/main/#home` it should go to home page
and also when i try `domain.com/#home` it should also go to same home page
not to forget that i want other controllers to be working fully.
i mean, `domain.com/othercontrollername/#function` should work.

what and how to achieve it, .htaccess or route php file..

i even tried this below route code.

```
$route['#+(:any)'] = "main/#+$1";
```

but i am no good in this routing or .htaccess files.

any ideas how to achieve it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// The below line is for the old controller to work as before
$route['main/(:any)'] = "main/$1"; 

//This line is for making other controllers work as before, you have to put them all
$route['virtualvault/(:any)'] = "virtualvault/$1";

//This is the last line; the order is important
$route['(:any)'] = "main/$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only those three URLs (home, search and login) to work without the controller name, just put the three of them in routes.php (`$route['login'] = "main/login";`, etc.) and use no wildcards in order to prevent other URLs from getting rerouted.

So, all of them should be:

```
$route['home'] = "main/home";
$route['search'] = "main/search";
$route['login'] = "main/login";
```

Comment: no, its not just three urls, i only gave example of these urls,
Isin't there any other better way, like .htaccess file or router function something??
yes one thing is common, that all of my url functions will have # as you can see in example.
i am using jquery bbq.

Comment: I still think it would be the best to make such a whitelist, either in routes.php or .htaccess... Otherwise, you won't be able to make the links work both ways (with `main` and without).